# Как правильно сделать индекс?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть БД, в которой следующие поля

```
id, parent_id, name
```

При этом parent_id = 0, если нет родителя, или = id родителя. Как правильно сделать индекс, чтобы нельзя было воткнуть невалидную запись (без родителя)?

При этом parent_id = null нельзя делать, с null не будет работать проверка на уникальность

```
UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_CATEGORY` (`parent_id` ASC, `name` ASC))
```

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял.

А почему бы не объявить parent_id NOT NULL?

Comment: Это то уже сделал, но как это защитит от вставки parent_id = 34563456, которого отродясь никогда не было?

Comment: Наверное, можно через хранимую процедуру выполнять проверку и вставку.


delimiter $$

create procedure inst(id int, parent int)

begin

If (select count(a.id) from a where a.id = parent) > 0 then

insert into a values(id, parent);

end if;

end $$


Но это нужно допиливать ибо еще вопросы появляются насчет некорректного ввода (не существует записей с параметром id, id = parent).

А не проще не давать пользователю напрямую вводить данные параметры и соответственно не дать ему вообще отослать вредные значения?
Или это веб?

Comment: Какая СУБД используется? Возможно, написать триггер при вставке новой записи, который бы анализировал бы существование id, если в parent_id его указали.

Comment: @IntegralAL, mysql же.

Но триггеры, как я понимаю, не имеют возможности прервать ход выполнения операции.

Comment: Пользователь туда вообще не будет ничего вводить "напрямую", туда будут аггрегироваться данные из нескольких десятков источников, общим весом ныне в 25 Гб - потом такие мелкие ошибки не выследишь, если что-то расползётся. Поэтому я закручиваю гайки со всех сторон, чтобы нельзя было не валидные записи воткнуть.
____

Спасибо, интересный вариант. Не самый быстрый, но зато более-менее рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Так:

```
create table tree (
  id int primary key,
  parent_id int,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tree` (`id`) 
);

insert into tree (id, parent_id) values
(0,0), -- нулевой элемент - корень дерева
(1,0),
(2,1);

insert into tree (id, parent_id) values (3,100500); -- тут будет ошибка
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/debf5f

Comment: Разве что возможен случай id = parent_id.

Comment: Не важно, человек сам сказал, что гайки закручивает, и как минимум возможна ситуация, когда parent_id не будет существовать, так что тут не угадаешь.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
И что дальше? Ваш вариант в чем состоит собственно? Создать индекс, а потом чистить гигабайты? Если человек говорит, что закручивает гайки, то в вашем случае придется делать что-то еще кроме создания индекса, хотя один вопрос назревает - для чего делать кучу дел, когда можно одной структурной единицей ограничиться и сразу предусмотреть варианты?

Вот именно потому, что я отталкиваюсь только от того, что говорит ТС и предлагаю определенное решение, которое можно свободно расширить и не лезть в другие дебри.

Answer (score 1):

[[@QuAzI](/users/15004/quazi)](/users/15004/quazi), можно еще следующим образом сделать.

Если в запрос передаются вместо paramId и paramParent конкретные значения

```
INSERT INTO a
SELECT paramId, paramParent FROM a
WHERE a.id = paramParent
```

Если предполагаемого родителя не найдется (нет такого id, которое равно paramParent), то и никаких изменений не произойдет.

**UPD:**
Опять же, если есть возможность реализовать алгоритм с помощью хранимой процедуры, то можно в теле процедуры проверять наличие записей по условию с помощью SELECT EXISTS:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(id int, parent int)
BEGIN
IF (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = parent)) THEN
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(id, parent);
END IF;
END $
```

Если необходимо, то остается только прикрутить проверку на равенство id и parent и проверку на существование id.

Другой вопрос - скорость я не измерял.

Answer (score 0):

Нате, старая добрая статья по работе с деревьями в MySQL. Также Вам советовали триггеры - здесь хорошие примеры: [раз](http://websiteprog.ru/sozdanie_derevev_xranenie_dannyx_na_primere_kategorij) и [два](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/17286/match=managing+trees+database).

Comment: А статья где? Ссылка идёт на текущий топик.

Comment: @QuAzI, действительно на топик...   
http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Answer (score -1):

Ввести фиктивного родителя с id=0.